# no php.in in my php environment of centos

Tags: php, linux

After make and make install PHP on centos, I ran `cp php.ini-dist /usr/local/php/etc/php.ini`.

It shows `cp: accessing /usr/local/php/etc/php.ini': Not a directory`.

I then used `phpinfo()` , it shows
Configure Command    `'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--enable-ftp' '--with-gd' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-gettext' '--with-mhash' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mcrypt' '--enable-soap' '--enable-zip' '--with-iconv=/usr/local/libiconv' '--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql' '--without-pear'`

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
```

when i looked the file in the `/etc` directory,there is no php.ini. how add it.thank u.

Comment: Do `mkdir -p /usr/local/php/etc` first.

Comment: @jack,when i run,mkdir -p /usr/local/php/etc  shows"mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/php/etc': File exists"

Comment: I see, in that case it seems that `/usr/local/php/etc` is a file ... check what's inside and remove it .. then run `mkdir` again.

Comment: etc no any suffix. how to open it?thank u

Answer (score 0):

In terminal/console (you need putty or kitty)

```
ssh user@ip
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

shows something like Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini.

> or

```
php -i |grep 'Configuration File'
```

Comment: thank u. when i use php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File" in the console. shows  -bash: php: command not found

Comment: ALTERNATIVE METHOD:

You can make a php file on your website, which run: <?php phpinfo(); ?>, and you can see the php.ini location under: "Loaded Configuration File".

Comment: i have done it. it shows Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc but i went to /etc. i didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the path to php.ini in the output of phpinfo(). See under "Loaded Configuration File"

[image]